# Android app, service only

Tags: android, service

I'm designing an app that is basically only a service.

It has no MainActivity... just a BroadcastReceiver and one Service. Every time I build and install, nothing happens. The broadcast receiver detects if the phone is connected to a WiFi network or not. If WiFi is not connected, it will stopService(), else it startService().

The service will check for Pebble app messages and execute certain commands on message receive. The problem is that without a MainActivity I have been unable to start the service.

Could it possibly because I have no `MainActivity`?

Comment: For what action your broadcast receiver is registered.

Answer (score 4):

Simple Background application stop working after Android 3.0 version.

Starting from Android 3.1, the system's package manager keeps track of applications that are in a stopped state and provides a means of controlling their launch from background processes and other applications.

System adds `FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` to all broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of stoppped applications. More at [Launch controls on stopped applications](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html).

As you have mentioned you just have a `BroadcastReceiver` and one `Service` and no `Activity` so the problem may be your `BroadcastReceiver` may never be started because of `FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` flag.

To receive broadcast your Application process should be in alive state. Android OS does not allow  `BroadcastReceiver` to receive some broadcast if the app´s process is not alive.

If you have an activity running,your process is alive and so your receiver is allowed to receive the broadcast.

What you can do is make a transparent activity without any UI with

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

and use `startService()` to start a service in background,then call `finish()` of `Activity`.As your service is running ,your process is alive,so the Android OS will let you to receive the broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Create a dummy `Activity` without `setcontentview()` and `startService()` from that `Activity` and `finish()` it.

In `manifest` remove launcher tag and `go to > Run As > Run Configuration > check Launch radiobutton` and select your `Activity` which dont have any view (without `setcontentview()`).

Answer (score 0):

`Could it possibly because I have no MainActivity?`,

No it is not because of mainActivity, You can start service without mainActivity also, So problem might be something else, for your reference check this below example,

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("", "in start service");
    Intent service = new Intent(context, rs.class);
    context.startService(service);
}
  }
```