# Error running 'myapplication': unable to determine activity name

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I'm trying to create an Android service. I don't want any application with interface to the user, only a receiver that will trigger when phone is turning on, then it will run the service. The service should do only background things such as reading notifications and passing them to a specified IP address (just an example, here in the file it's not configured like that).

The `AndroidMenifest.xml` file I have look like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application>
        <service android:name=".MainService" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name=".ReceiveBootMessage" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

As far as I know it should be fine but it still says the above error. I would like to hear for any advice from you.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76921843/error-running-app-unable-to-determine-activity-name

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, Hey first of all thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it isnt helping, I already saw that question and I've added the things mentioned in there... It still not working.

Comment: Your `category` in intent filter should be `DEFAULT`, not `LAUNCHER`.

Comment: @Ariczek Tried that, still the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android app, service only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652350/android-app-service-only)

Comment: @tomerpacific not so much, as I can see there suggesting to create a dummy activity, which sounds to me as a bad workaround (I also tried that) only the last answer not suggesting that but it also doesnt saying what you should do

Comment: Your Service or BroadcastReceiver won't ever run until the user chooses to manually open your app...which requires an Activity to open.

Comment: @ianhanniballake so, is there any reason at all to use BroadcastReceivier? I mean, if I reboot the phone the app will shut down and will not receive any events (such as phone turning up) from the system

Comment: @ianhanniballake Also, I would love to get a reference to the source you know that from or any relevant other sources, as I'm trying to get an answer for this for a full day and it doesn't seem like there is something about it